# How to install Ubuntu on Acer aspire 5s

Tags: laptop, acer, aspire

Please help for installing Ubuntu

Comment: Most Acer need UEFI update & SSD firmware update if you have SSD. You may also need to change from RAID/Intel RST to AHCI. Newer Acer -  CTRL S on the main Tab in BIOS to get the option to change SATA to AHCI Acer also has an unique requirement after install of setting "trust" on Ubuntu's .efi boot files. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot
 &  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so get Ubuntu bootable on a usb drive or any medium your system would support... Now try following these simple steps...

1. Boot your Computer
2. Get into the boot menu by pressing the required keyboard key(s)
3. Now choose the name of the storage device you have Ubuntu burned into.
4. Select "Install Ubuntu" when it loads up.
5. Select your preferred language and keyboard type.
6. The rest should be easy to follow unless you want to make a dual boot or something of that sort.